# SlabText not to render to the full width

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm having a bit of a strange issue with the jQuery SlabText plugin. When the page loads, the plugin fires but the text does not span the width of it's container as expected.

However, if I call `.slabText` again (on a hover event for example), it renders the ttext absolutely fine. Here is an image that shows what's happening:

[image: Issue explanation]

I'm not doing anything special when I call the plugin to begin with:

But the site I'm running it on does have a fair bit of JS running (but with no errors). **Can anyone suggest what may be causing this** so that I can troubleshoot the problem?! Thanks in advance.

[I can give further information if needed.]

You should be able to see this occurring on my 'coming soon' page: http://ponderacreative.com/

Comment: A fiddle/live demo would be specially useful.

Comment: I've just added a link (http://ponderacreative.com/) to a live page which shows the problem. Thanks for looking @FabrícioMatté

Comment: No problem, though I cannot reproduce it - the text fits the container horizontally on page load perfectly on my Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Hmm, does it look the same if you refresh the page? I have found that (on occasion) it loads correctly, then on refreshes the error presents itself. I've put up another temporary page (http://ponderacreative.com/our-approach.php) which displays this issue... on my pc at least!

Comment: Mhm yeah, that one is failing on Chrome stable after refresh sometimes.

Comment: The only real difference to the pages is that I've converted it to PHP... mainly to pull in repeating content. Other than that... I can't think what else is different.

Comment: Did you figure it out? I have similar issue in Chrome.

Comment: Nope, not as of yet! In fact it's making me consider other options to achieve a similar output. Do pass on any knowledge if you get close to an answer!

Comment: @Sheixt I'm having a similar problem as well - wrong widths on initial load, then fixed on reload.  

I went to ponderacreative.com and see that you seem to have made it work - what was your solution?